# Newletter - teaser with fixed height

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, newsletter

I am developing a newsletter template for use in email and I would like to have a table row/div which can't be higher than a certain value so that the text is not displayed in case it is too long.

So far I tried two different approaches:
With tables only:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="teaser" style="table-layout:fixed; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap;letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="w480 normal-text" height="64" width="92" border="1" valign="top" align="left" style="color: #6f6f6f; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; border: #6f6f6f;">
<a href="#" target="blank" style="border:0px;text-decoration:none;color: #6f6f6f;">
<img src='testImage.jpg' alt='' style='border:0px' />
</a>
</td>
<td width="298" height="64" valign="top" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<h1 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 15px; vertical-align: top; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<a href="#" target="blank">
<span style="color: #6f6f6f; line-height: inherit; text-decoration: none; position: relative; letter-spacing: 0.03em; top: -2px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
Quias alitatem <br />qui cullat
</span>
</a>
</h1>
<a href="#" target="blank" style="border:0px;text-decoration:none;">
<p class="normal-text no-overflow" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; overflow: hidden; margin: 4px 0px 0px;color: #6f6f6f">
WelIpsamus pe invenda quiatur? Quias alitatem qui cullat lique num et molor sitempo rionse. WelIpsamus pe invenda quiatur? Quias alitatem qui cullat lique num et molor sitempo rionse.
</p>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

With tables and divs:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="teaser" style="table-layout:fixed; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap;letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="w480 normal-text" height="64" width="92" border="1" valign="top" align="left" style="color: #6f6f6f; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; border: #6f6f6f;">
<img src='testImage.jpg' alt='' />
</td>
<td width="298" height="64" valign="top" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<div style='height:64px; overflow:hidden;'>
<h1 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 15px; vertical-align: top; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<span style="color: #6f6f6f; line-height: inherit; text-decoration: none; position: relative; letter-spacing: 0.03em; top: -2px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
Quias alitatem <br />qui cullat
</span>
</h1>
<p class="normal-text no-overflow" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; margin: 4px 0px 0px;">
WelIpsamus pe invenda quiatur? Quias alitatem qui cullat lique num et molor sitempo rionse. WelIpsamus pe invenda quiatur? Quias alitatem qui cullat lique num et molor sitempo rionse.
</p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

They both work well in the preview in any browser. But when the email is received the height of the row/div is not respected. Is there any way of getting the desired result?

Comment: Which email client are you checking with?

Comment: the standard email client of iPhone 4

Comment: Probably such a result is not possible for newsletter?

Answer (score 0):

Try `table-layout:fixed;`. it will force the table to take priority over the content.

Not sure if it is 100% supported in email, so let me know how you go testing it.

Comment: (as you can see in my first example, I already tried that way)